# How can I copy a URL in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a test case set up in Selenium IDE to log me into a web page and when the webpage launches the URL is unique.

I was wondering if there is a way for selenium to copy the unique URL and store it in a list for me to view later.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you you're looking for?

http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2012/11/storelocation-and-storetitle-commands.html

1. Login
2. Wait until the URL you want appear
3. Store that URL to an variable
4. Create an array
5. Store the variable to the array
6. Repeat with other URLs

I'll edit later since I'm having sudden task right now :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While this link may answer the question, it would improve your answer to include the relevant parts of the link here.  Links can go dead, rending your answer useless.